# startup mount issues with Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows-server, startup

I am trying to simply shutdown and restart an Oracle db instance on a Windows Server 2008 machine (Oracle 11.2.0).  Logged in via sqlplus, I issue the command `shutdown immediate;`.  I get the

```
Database closed.  
Database dismounted.  
ORACLE instance shut down
```

reponses.  I exit out of sqlplus, and try to log back in (ORACLE_SID is set correctly) so I can issue the `startup mount;` command, but I get the

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

error.  All of the Windows services involving my database **dantest3** are started.  Doing research, I found the oradim command, but while that starts my database and allowing me to login, that is the full startup, and I want to only be in "mount" mode.

I am logging in with the following command -

```
sqlplus sys/[passwordforacct]@dantest3 as sysdba
```

If I try the simple `sqlplus / as sydba`, I get a

```
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

oradim command -

```
oradim -start -sid dantest3
```

Requested variables -

```
TNS_ADMIN = C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
ORACLE_SID = dantest3
ORACLE_HOME_11gR2 = C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
```

Comment: What exact sqlplus command are you issuing?

Comment: Have you verified that the service listener is started ? if i remember well it is mandatory on windows platforms, even for local connections.

Answer (score 1):

Is the environment variable LOCAL set? this will cause sqlplus to connect to a TNS alias instead of directly to the local database instance.

Your other problem with starting it into mount, you are missing a parameter to oradim -STARTTYPE srvc.  All of the options can be seen by typing `oradim /?`

to start just the service so that you can manually start to mount use

```
oradim -start -sid dantest3 -starttype srvc
```

At this point the database will not be registered with the listener so you will still need to connect without using the listener.